# String constructing issue in coverity

Tags: java

I am working with a coverity issue . In my code ,

```
    props =  
    StandardUtils.getProperties(="/Dir/tomcat/properties/lib/standardlib_" + 
    cust_id + ".properties, inst_Id);

This vulnerability is found by my coverity server and showing the message

"CID 127299 (#1 of 1): Filesystem path, filename, or URI manipulation
```

(PATH_MANIPULATION)
   4. sink: Constructing a path or URI using the tainted value 
   /Dir/tomcat/properties/lib/standardlib_" + 
    cust_id + ".properties, inst_Id. This may allow an attacker to access, 
   modify, or test the existence of critical or sensitive files "

Then i assign this String to a String variable again did my coverity scan but 
  showing the same error message " "

```
    String loc="/Dir/tomcat/properties/lib/standardlib_" + 
    cust_id + ".properties";
    props = StandardUtils.getProperties(loc, inst_id);
```

But issue is still exists .

coverity suggest that "Path manipulation vulnerabilities can be addressed by 
   proper input validation. Blacklisting characters that allow unsafe path 
   traversal can improve the safety of the input, but the recommended approach 
   is to whitelist the set of expected characters. This should exclude absolute 
   paths and upward directory traversal."

These type of issues are reported multiple places in my code .

How can we resolve these type of issues ? Can any one help me on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read up on [path traversal](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal), but basically, your code is still vulnerable to an attack, while it may not be a path traversal attack specifically this may be subject to an [indirect object reference](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Insecure_Direct_Object_References_(OTG-AUTHZ-004)) attack.

What if `cust_id` looked like this:

```
String cust_id = request.getParameter("cust_id");
```

and i provided a url

```
http://your_server.com:8080/?cust_id=123
```

then this:

```
String loc = "/Dir/tomcat/properties/lib/standardlib_" + 
        cust_id + ".properties";
```

would expand too:

```
String loc = "/Dir/tomcat/properties/lib/standardlib_123.properties";
```

So assuming there are different log files for different customers, it may be possible to view the file for someone else.

To fix this, you either need to validate `cust_id`, or check access for it somehow.

You can then safely mark it as a false-positive once you have fixed the issue.